# Recurrent class list SimpleXML

Tags: java, android, class, simple-framework

i have this file XML:

```
<Category id="IDCT">
 <Name>Name Category1</Name>
  <Category id "IRCT+1">
    <Name>Namce child Category1>
  </Category>
</Category>
```

And my class category :

```
enter @Element(name = "Category")
public class Category {

@Attribute
private String id;
@ElementList(entry = "Name", inline = true, required = true)
public List<Name> name;
@ElementList(name = "Category", inline = true, required = false)
private List<Category> categories;

public List<Category> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Name> getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(List<Name> name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", categories="
            + categories + "]";
}

}
```

The problem is that I can read only the first category (father), and not the children.

Note: Children may be more than one and each child can have in turn their children.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `XmlAccessorType. I provide Reading`Recursive XML`ref. Put`category.xml` into classpath.

category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<category id="C1" name="Programming">
    <category id="C1.1" name="Java">
        <category id="C1.1.1" name="Core Java"/>
        <category id="C1.1.1" name="Java EE"/>
    </category>
    <category id="C1.2" name=".Net">
        <category id="C1.2.1" name=".C#"/>
        <category id="C1.2.2" name="ASP.Net"/>
    </category>
</category>
```

Category.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="category")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Category {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name="category")
    private List<Category> subCategoryList;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Category> getSubCategoryList() {
        return subCategoryList;
    }
    public void setSubCategoryList(List<Category> subCategoryList) {
        this.subCategoryList = subCategoryList;
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Category.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Category category = (Category) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("category.xml"));
        System.out.println(category.getName());
        System.out.println(category.getSubCategoryList().size());
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(category, System.out);
    }

}
```

Output

```
Programming
2
-------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<category id="C1" name="Programming">
    <category id="C1.1" name="Java">
        <category id="C1.1.1" name="Core Java"/>
        <category id="C1.1.1" name="Java EE"/>
    </category>
    <category id="C1.2" name=".Net">
        <category id="C1.2.1" name=".C#"/>
        <category id="C1.2.2" name="ASP.Net"/>
    </category>
</category>
```

Comment: I had to customize a bit your code, but it works! 
thank you very much